# what does it mean when they say some values agree within some percentage?

Tags: percentage, agreement-statistics

Maybe a silly question, as the question states, what exactly does it mean when a comparison is written in percentage? Will it be better to have let's say an agreement of 5% or 10%? In order words, when they say some results agree within some percentage, which percentage is better?

Answer (score 1):

> $\alpha$ and $\beta$ agree within $5\%$

is an abbreviated way of saying

> Up to an error tolerance of $5\%$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the same.

The word "agree" sometimes used in the sense of "these two values agree, that is, they are the same."